# Automatically creating worksheets based on a list in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a new sheet(Slave) with the name as entered in the cells A5:A50 in (master) sheet and copy the contents of the (template)sheet in the newly created slave sheet. I have got one program as below which closely matched with my requirement but 1) it doesnt take new values which i edit and create a new slave in the range provided i.e it is not dynamic and 2) i want to run the macro everytime i enter the value in the specified range.

Help would be highly appreciated

```
Sub CreateAndNameWorksheets()
Dim c As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In Sheets("Master").Range("A5:A50")
    Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    With c
        ActiveSheet.Name = .Value
        .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
            "'" & .Text & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=.Text
    End With
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Look into the [`Worksheet_Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event. It will assist in your both of your points (which seem kind of the same, actually.)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the "Master" Sheet, every time you change a cell in the Range("A5:A50") it will run the desired code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If (Target.Parent.Name = Range("A1:A50").Parent.Name) Then
        Dim ints As Range
        Set ints = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A5:A50"))
        If (Not (ints Is Nothing)) Then

            'insert code here

        End If
    End If


End Sub
```